# Get data of year on month basis in percentage

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have been wondering on google to find solution to my problem but all I get is beyond my understanding because I am new to database.
I am using Mysql.

**Problem**

I have thousands of records in table out of which I have to show
month wise percentage of records of whole current year. Following is structure of **order** table

[image]

This is how I want to show data

[image]

Comment: What do those numbers represent? Summing `numberOfItems`?

Comment: it represents total number of products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd cross join two queries. The first would sum the number of products sold each month and the second would sum the total number of products sold that year:

```
SELECT     `month`, `num_month` / `num_year` * 100 AS "percent"
FROM       (SELECT   MONTH(`dateOfOrder`) AS "month", COUNT(*) AS num_month
            FROM     `order`
            WHERE    YEAR(`dateOfOrder`) = 2018
            GROUP BY MONTH(`dateOfOrder`) a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_year
            FROM   `order`
            WHERE  YEAR(`dateOfOrder`) = 2018) b
```